# Flink SQL left join inserting null values to right table even after showing matching records

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have been doing left join on a stream data in apache flink sql i.e. converting two datastream api to the Flink SQL, however it is giving the null for example:

table 1

| id | Dept |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | Dept 1 |
| id 2 | Dept 2 |
| id 3 | Dept 3 |
| id 4 | Dept 4 |

Table 2

| id | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | Employee 1 |
| id 2 | Employee 2 |
| id 1 | Employee 3 |
| id 3 | Employee 4 |

I am doing left join on the ID:
left table: table1
right table: table2

it gives output as

| id | Dept | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id 1 | Dept 1 | Employee 1 |
| id 2 | Dept 2 | Employee 2 |
| id 1 | Dept 1 | Employee 3 |
| id 3 | Dept 3 | Employee 4 |
| id 1 | Dept 1 | null |

Data is going on for n values

Behaviour of this flink sql join in not understood, as it is giving null for id 1 after matching value with right table

```
Table joinResult = streamTableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT join_source_1.id, join_source_1.dept, join_source_2.employeeName FROM join_source_1 LEFT JOIN join_source_2 ON join_source_1.id = join_source_2.id”);
```

Expecting to get non-null value in the right table once the record is matched

Also the Data is consumed from the kafka streaming source

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: You've indicated that table1 is both the left and right table. Maybe that's a typo? Also, could you please share the actual SQL query for a reproducible example?

Comment: Added the sample query

Comment: Is this a simplified example of something that happened once in production, or is this easily and deterministically reproducible?

Comment: This is easily reproducible, also tried joining with windowing but result is the same. I have worked on Kafka Stream API as well there as well same behaviour is seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only seen unexpected results like this from Kafka in situations where a too-short retention policy kicks in and removes the data that was previously available.

Comment: Any observation in scenarios about how much retention policy period is consistent would be helpful